# DirectWriteでHello, Worldを表示するプログラムがビルドエラーになる

Tags: windows, visual-studio

WindowsのDirectWriteでHelloWorldをWindowに表示するコードを描いたのですがうまく動きません。なぜでしょうか?

WndProcのWM_PAINT内でDirectWriteを使って文字を描画しているのですが、
どうやら、ビルドの時にエラーが出ているようです。
`fatal error LNK1120: 1 件の未解決の外部参照`
というエラーが発生します。

OS:Windows10 Home

MyDWrite.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
```

MyDWrite.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyDWRITE.h"



#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
template <class T> inline void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}
// グローバル変数:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // 現在のインターフェイス
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // タイトル バーのテキスト
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // メイン ウィンドウ クラス名

ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *pIRenderTarget;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *pIRedBrush = NULL;
IDWriteTextFormat *pITextFormat = NULL;
IDWriteFactory *pIDWriteFactory = NULL;

// このコード モジュールに含まれる関数の宣言を転送します:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MYDWRITE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // アプリケーションの初期化を実行します:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYDWRITE));

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}


ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYDWRITE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_MYDWRITE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // グローバル変数にインスタンス処理を格納します。

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  関数: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  目的:    メイン ウィンドウのメッセージを処理します。
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - アプリケーション メニューの処理
//  WM_PAINT    - メイン ウィンドウの描画
//  WM_DESTROY  - 中止メッセージを表示して戻る
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: HDC を使用する描画コードをここに追加してください...
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
                    __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
                    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pIDWriteFactory));
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = pIDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(
                    L"源ノ角ゴシック Code JP",
                    NULL,
                    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
                    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
                    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
                    10.0f * 96.0f / 72.0f,
                    L"ja-JP",
                    &pITextFormat);
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = pIRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red),
                    &pIRedBrush);
            }
            D2D1_RECT_F layoutRect = D2D1::RectF(0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                pIRenderTarget->DrawTextW(
                    L"Hello, World",
                    wcslen(L"Hello, World"),
                    pITextFormat,
                    layoutRect,
                    pIRedBrush
                );

            }
            SafeRelease(&pIRedBrush);
            SafeRelease(&pITextFormat);
            SafeRelease(&pIDWriteFactory);



            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// バージョン情報ボックスのメッセージ ハンドラーです。
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linker Tools Error LNK1120](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1120)では次のように説明されています。

> Error LNK1120 reports the count (number) of unresolved external symbol errors for this link operation. Most unresolved external symbol errors are reported individually by Linker Tools Error LNK2001 and Linker Tools Error LNK2019, which precede this error message, once for each unresolved external symbol error.

つまりLNK1120はunresolved external symbol errorの数を集計したサマリー報告でしかなく、これそのものは本質的にはエラーではありません。根本的にはこれよりも手前で発生しているはずのLNK2001やLNK2019で報告されているunresolved external symbol errorを解消する必要があります。しかし質問文にはこれらエラーが挙げられていないため解決できません。

---

推測ですが、[`DWriteCreateFactory()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-dwritecreatefactory#requirements)を呼び出しています。ドキュメントには

> Header : dwrite.h
>   Library : Dwrite.lib
>   DLL : Dwrite.dll

と書かれているようにヘッダーファイルとしては`dwrite.h`を指定する必要があり、質問文のコードでもそのように書かれています。同様にライブラリとしては`Dwrite.lib`を指定する必要がありますが、質問文にはこれが書かれていません。エラーの原因はこれかもしれません。その場合、

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Dwrite.lib")
```

が必要です。