# DirectWriteでHello, Worldを表示するプログラムを実行しても何も表示されない

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

[DirectWriteでHello, Worldを表示するプログラムがビルドエラーになる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47253/directwrite%e3%81%a7hello-world%e3%82%92%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%81%8c%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b/47256#47256)
の続きです。
ビルドエラーは起きなくなったのですが、実行しても何も表示されません。
なぜでしょうか?
デバッグ実行すると、白いWidnowが表示されるだけでHello, Worldが表示されません。
特にエラーも出ておらずWindowを閉じると正常に終了します。

---

### 追記

実行している間はカーソルがとても早く切り替わることに気づきました。(waitと普通の形状に1秒間に5~6回切り替わる)
なぜ、このようなことがおこるのでしょうか?

CreateSolidBrushでthisがnullptrであるというエラーを修正したのでMyDWRITE.cppを再掲します。

```
// MyDWRITE.cpp : アプリケーションのエントリ ポイントを定義します。
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyDWRITE.h"



#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
template <class T> inline void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}
// グローバル変数:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // 現在のインターフェイス
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // タイトル バーのテキスト
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // メイン ウィンドウ クラス名
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *pIRenderTarget;



// このコード モジュールに含まれる関数の宣言を転送します:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
ID2D1Factory *m_pDirect2dFactory;


int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: ここにコードを挿入してください。

    // グローバル文字列を初期化しています。

    int err = LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MYDWRITE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // アプリケーションの初期化を実行します:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYDWRITE));

    MSG msg;
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    HRESULT hr = CreateRenderTarget(hWnd, m_pDirect2dFactory, pIRenderTarget);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"Hello", L"World", MB_OK);
    }


    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // メイン メッセージ ループ:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  関数: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  目的: ウィンドウ クラスを登録します。
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYDWRITE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_MYDWRITE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   関数: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   目的: インスタンス ハンドルを保存して、メイン ウィンドウを作成します。
//
//   コメント:
//
//        この関数で、グローバル変数でインスタンス ハンドルを保存し、
//        メイン プログラム ウィンドウを作成および表示します。
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // グローバル変数にインスタンス処理を格納します。


   return TRUE;
}

//
//  関数: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  目的:    メイン ウィンドウのメッセージを処理します。
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - アプリケーション メニューの処理
//  WM_PAINT    - メイン ウィンドウの描画
//  WM_DESTROY  - 中止メッセージを表示して戻る
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // 選択されたメニューの解析:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            Draw(pIRenderTarget);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// バージョン情報ボックスのメッセージ ハンドラーです。
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

---

### 追記2

MyDWRITE.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Dwrite.lib")



HRESULT CreateRenderTarget(HWND hWnd, ID2D1Factory *pDirect2dFactory, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *&pIRenderTarget) {
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
            &pDirect2dFactory);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pDirect2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd),
            &pIRenderTarget);
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT Draw(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *pIRenderTarget) {
    // &m_pDirect2dFactory
    // &pIRenderTarget
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush *pIRedBrush = NULL;
    IDWriteTextFormat *pITextFormat = NULL;
    IDWriteFactory *pIDWriteFactory = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
            __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
            reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pIDWriteFactory));
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(pIRenderTarget->GetHwnd(), L"Hello", L"Cat", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pIDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(
            L"源ノ角ゴシック Code JP",
            NULL,
            DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
            DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
            DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
            10.0f * 96.0f / 72.0f,
            L"ja-jp",
            &pITextFormat);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(pIRenderTarget->GetHwnd(), L"Hello", L"Cat", MB_OK);
        OutputDebugString(L"IDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat");
        return hr;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pIRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red),
            &pIRedBrush);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(pIRenderTarget->GetHwnd(), L"Hello", L"Cat", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        D2D1_RECT_F layoutRect = D2D1::RectF(0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f);
        pIRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
        pIRenderTarget->DrawTextW(
            L"Hello, World",
            wcslen(L"Hello, World"),
            pITextFormat,
            layoutRect,
            pIRedBrush
        );
        MessageBox(pIRenderTarget->GetHwnd(), L"Hello", L"Cat", MB_OK);
        pIRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    }
    else {
        OutputDebugString(L"End of error");
        MessageBox(pIRenderTarget->GetHwnd(), L"Hello", L"Cat", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }
    return hr;
}
```

---

MyDWRITE.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyDWRITE.h"



#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
template <class T> inline void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}
// グローバル変数:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // 現在のインターフェイス
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // タイトル バーのテキスト
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // メイン ウィンドウ クラス名

ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *pIRenderTarget;
ID2D1Factory *m_pDirect2dFactory;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *pIRedBrush = NULL;
IDWriteTextFormat *pITextFormat = NULL;
IDWriteFactory *pIDWriteFactory = NULL;

// このコード モジュールに含まれる関数の宣言を転送します:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: ここにコードを挿入してください。

    // グローバル文字列を初期化しています。
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MYDWRITE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // アプリケーションの初期化を実行します:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYDWRITE));

    MSG msg;

    // メイン メッセージ ループ:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  関数: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  目的: ウィンドウ クラスを登録します。
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYDWRITE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_MYDWRITE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   関数: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   目的: インスタンス ハンドルを保存して、メイン ウィンドウを作成します。
//
//   コメント:
//
//        この関数で、グローバル変数でインスタンス ハンドルを保存し、
//        メイン プログラム ウィンドウを作成および表示します。
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // グローバル変数にインスタンス処理を格納します。

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  関数: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  目的:    メイン ウィンドウのメッセージを処理します。
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - アプリケーション メニューの処理
//  WM_PAINT    - メイン ウィンドウの描画
//  WM_DESTROY  - 中止メッセージを表示して戻る
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // 選択されたメニューの解析:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: HDC を使用する描画コードをここに追加してください...
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
                    &m_pDirect2dFactory);

            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
                    D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd),
                    &pIRenderTarget);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
                    __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
                    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pIDWriteFactory));
            }



            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = pIDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(
                    L"源ノ角ゴシック Code JP",
                    NULL,
                    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
                    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
                    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
                    10.0f * 96.0f / 72.0f,
                    L"ja-JP",
                    &pITextFormat);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = pIRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red),
                    &pIRedBrush);
            }
            D2D1_RECT_F layoutRect = D2D1::RectF(0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                pIRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
                pIRenderTarget->DrawTextW(
                    L"Hello, World",
                    wcslen(L"Hello, World"),
                    pITextFormat,
                    layoutRect,
                    pIRedBrush
                );
                pIRenderTarget->EndDraw();
            }

        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        SafeRelease(&pIRedBrush);
        SafeRelease(&pITextFormat);
        SafeRelease(&pIDWriteFactory);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// バージョン情報ボックスのメッセージ ハンドラーです。
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: タグについて補足しておくと`template`関数が含まれているのでC++言語です。

Comment: [回答を受けた後で全く別の質問に編集しないでください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2602/4236)。回答内容と矛盾します。新たな質問が生まれたのであれば、新に質問し直してください。

Comment: ロールバックしました。
申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 関数　Draw(pIRenderTarget);　に問題があるかもしれません。
この関数はソースコード掲載されていないので何とも言えませんけど。

Comment: Draw関数を追加しました
MyDWRITE.hに記載されています

Answer (score 3):

> 特にエラーも出ておらず

と書かれていますが、実際のコードは「特にエラーチェックをしておらず」です。例えば`wWinMain`の処理では

> ```
> LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
> LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MYDWRITE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
> MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
> ```

と各関数は実行結果を返しているにもかかわらず、それを捨てています。各戻り値を確認し、正常でなければエラー値を確認することから始めてください。

Comment: LoadStringWの3行は最初にWin32のプロジェクトをVS2017で作成したときに生成されていたものなのですが、エラー確認すべきなのでしょうか?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter  正常に動作するのであればエラー確認するかは自由です。しかし、正常動作していない場合にエラーが発生することを期待するのであれば、エラー確認の後にエラーを発生させるべきです。

Answer (score 0):

WM_PAINT受領時、

```
BeginPaint();
EndPaint();
```

で、SDK側の再描画要求を完了させる必要があります。
これにより、無用な再描画要求の頻繁な発生を抑えることができます。
まず、これをやってみてはどうでしょう。チラチラしなくなるかと思います。

上記コードの直下で、レンダ(本件はHWND型のレンダ)による描画 Draw(・・・)を行ってみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: `BeginPaint();
EndPaint();
Draw(hWnd);`
とやってみたところ、カーソルはチラチラしなくなったのですが、Hello, Worldは表示されませんでした。